# Hardware not getting recognized on Ubuntu 13.04 after broken boot

Tags: 13.04, boot, grub2, usb

I had set the boot preference to USB drive on my desktop which was running on Ubuntu 13.04. Yesterday I plugged in a USB and on switching on the comp it started to boot from the USB drive. When I saw that I immediately pulled the USB out (my bad!) and the comp was stuck. But when I re started it, it booted normally but gets stuck on the login screen. The OS does not recognize either the keyboard nor the mouse. I tried using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but that did not help. The link that Boot Repair provided me is http://paste.ubuntu.com/6092970/ My system is also running Win8 and it doesn't have any problem. Its urgent that I fix it soon so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be an issue with a broken Kernel image.
Just log into command-line/Terminal and run
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image`

See if the issue is fixed after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the problem. During the broken boot my kernel Linux 3.8.0-29 generic had become corrupt. When I tried booting from an older version of the Linux kernel, it booted up normally. So now I just have to re install the broken kernel!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image`